# Refreshing a JSON filled chart's content every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to build a small application, which loads data from mySQL (measurement values), and creates a chart from it using FusionChart. I'd like to implement a function, which refreshes the chart's contents every 5 seconds. Since i study as an electrical engineer, i'm not really familiar with jQuery and AJAX, so i would appreciate any help.

Here is my index.php, with one chart:

```
<?php include("connect.php"); ?>

<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="chart"></div>

<?php include("charts.php") ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my charts.php:

```
<?php echo"

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
FusionCharts.ready(function(){
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
\"type\": \"column2d\",
\"renderAt\": \"chart\",
\"width\": \"100%\",
\"height\": \"auto\",
\"dataFormat\": \"json\",
\"dataSource\":  {
\"chart\": {
\"caption\": \"Monthly revenue for last year\",
\"subCaption\": \"Harry's SuperMart\",
\"xAxisName\": \"Month\",
\"yAxisName\": \"Revenues (In USD)\",
\"theme\": \"fint\"
},
\"data\": [";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM voltage");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "{\"label\":\"" . "$row[id]" . "\",\"value\":\"" . "$row[value]" . "\"},";
}
echo "]
}

});
revenueChart.render();
})
</script>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your script in two:

- One script that shows the main javascript - and putting that outside of php makes it a lot more readable and maintainable
- One script that generates your data object and that can be called through ajax.

Note that you should not build json manually, use `json_encode()` instead

Your first script would look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    theme: "fint"
  },
  data:
<?php
include 'your_data_generating_script';
?>
}
...
```

And the second script - the data generating script - would simply return the required json string:

```
// set up environment, db connetion, etc.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM voltage");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[] = array("label" => $row['id'], "value" => $row['value']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now you use `setTimeout()` in your javascript to call a function after for example your 5 seconds and in that function you can do your ajax call, process the results and set a new timeout.